# How to find a property file matching a pattern in a group of JAR files?

Tags: bash, files, search, zip

I'm using bash shell.  I have a group of JAR files in directories at different levels

```
> find . -name "*.jar"
/tmp/jars/META-INF/lib/jackson-datatype-jdk8.jar
/tmp/jars/lib/my-custom.jar
...
```

I would like to see if any of these JAR files contains a properties file whose file name matches "test-*.properties".  I would prefer not to unzip each JAR file and search through its contents.  Is there a way I can figure this information out?

Answer (score 1):

Something will need to poke around inside the archive, though this can
be done with an archive listing command such as `unzip -l` rather than
having to extract all the files:

```
find . -name \*.jar -exec sh -c \
  'jar --list --file={} | grep -q '\''test-.*\.properties'\'' && printf "%s\n" {}' \;
```

Maybe `unzip -l` might be faster but harder to parse? `jar` seemed more
sluggish to get itself up off disk for me.